# Do I need inheritdoc over an explicit interface implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, interface

The title is pretty self explanatory. Do I need inheritdoc over an explicit interface implementation?

```cs
public sealed class WebSocketPipe : IWebSocketPipe
{
    // TODO: /// <inheritdoc /> ???
    async Task IWebSocketPipe.StartAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

```cs
/// <summary>
///     A <see cref="IDuplexPipe" /> over a <see cref="WebSocket" /> which can be
///     used for reading and writing to it.
/// </summary>
public interface IWebSocketPipe : IDuplexPipe
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Starts populating the <see cref="IDuplexPipe.Input" /> with incoming data from the underlying
    ///     <see cref="WebSocket" /> as well as sending outgoing data written to the <see cref="IDuplexPipe.Output" />
    ///     and finishes when either are completed (or an explicit call to <see cref="StopAsync" /> is performed).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uri"></param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task StartAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Completes both the <see cref="IDuplexPipe.Input" /> and <see cref="IDuplexPipe.Output" />
    ///     of the duplex pipe, cancels any pending reads from the application and closes the underlying
    ///     <see cref="WebSocket" />.
    /// </summary>
    Task StopAsync();
}
```

Comment: Define "need". If the question is "will my code compile if I have both XML documentation and treat warnings as errors turned on in the configuration", then it's fairly straightforward to discover the answer. If that's not it though, it's not clear what definition of "need" you're working with.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I don't have these rules in my .editorconfig file, but I would like to enable them.